# curl corrupting terminal

Tags: curl

When I try to view the zip file with `curl` the terminal is corrupted. And after that all the character we typed cannot be recognized as they will be shown as unrecognizable Unicode. I curl the zip below:

```
curl http://udacity.github.io/ud595-shell/stuff.zip
```

I am asking as I'm curious about this. How is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `curl` like that, it will output the contents of the Zip-file to the terminal (`curl` writes to standard output by default). This may well corrupt the terminal, just as when you `cat` a compressed file or any other binary file.

To save the file, use `curl -O ...`. This will save the file with its original name (`stuff.zip`) in the current directory.

To save it with another name, use either `curl -o newname ...` or `curl ... >newname`.

Comment: Thanks, as a side question, do we have to close the terminal after it corrupts or retrieve on the runtime?

Comment: @vusan You could try `reset`. If that doesn't work, close the terminal and open a new one.

Comment: `reset` is working. in my case.

Comment: When you have a question, "ask a question" is the right place for it, not comments.  You will find that your side question [has](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93765/) [been](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10570/) [asked](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274482/) [many](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/) [times](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295871/) here.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` reads the zip file and prints it to stdout. To redirect curls output to a file called `stuff.zip` you need to state

```
curl http://udacity.github.io/ud595-shell/stuff.zip -o stuff.zip
```

> -o, --output FILE   Write to FILE instead of stdout