# PC speaker beep and messy terminal font due to dd if=/dev/sda?

Tags: terminal, tty, terminal-emulator

When running

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda
```

the internal PC speaker makes sounds. Also all fonts, even the prompt and typing input has different characters such as "♡" or "•".

If you need to know more, comment please.

What I usually do is of=/dev/null or >>/dev/null for reading performance testing and for spinning up the optical drive (with `count=1 iflag=direct skip=500000`), of which I skip to LBA 500000 to put the laser lens in the center of the data part. But I wanted to try out once what happens if I do not redirect the output anywhere, and that happened.

Fun fact: The same happens to Windows too.

Comment: You aren't specifying an output, so it goes to `stdout`.  Since it is all sorts of non-printable data, that is what you get, expressed the "best" way your system can

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274482/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245753/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287465/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93765/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302548/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295871/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10570/ .

Comment: @JdeBP How did you find all these related questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is roughly what happens:

1. Your `dd` command does not have an [`of=...`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) argument so it sends data to stdout.
2. And as you are running the command in a terminal the stdout of the running process is connected to the terminal.
3. Terminals can display text and interpret [control sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). Depending on your terminal type there are sequences to change the font or the color or the position of the cursor or to ring the bell (beep) and so on.
4. Your hard disk (`/dev/sda`) contains a lot of different data and there are surely some terminal control sequences in there by pure chance.

So you are sending a lot of text & control sequences to your terminal and it dutifully tries to display and interpret it.

Answer (score 4):

As Lucas said it's because of random data just happening to contain terminal control codes.

To fix it, run the command:

```
reset
```

Comment: You can also type this "blind" if your font/size/color in the terminal is a total mess.  Sometimes you have to hit CTRL-C first to delete any text that was put in your command line or to get out of the readline-vi-command-mode (depending on your shell setting).